# Discrete uniform random variable having variance 1

Tags: r, statistics, discrete-mathematics, uniform, variance

I would like to plot in R a discrete uniform random variable having variance 1, with an interval of [-a,a].

I have tried using Var(X)= (n^2-1)/12

Then getting that n should be `n = sqrt(13)`
Plugging this into

n=b-a+1=a-(-a)+1
a=(sqrt(13)-1)/2 = 1.302776

Trying this in R with the code

```
X <- sample(-1.302276:1.30227,1000, replace=TRUE)
```

The variance becomes around 0.65

Comment: I don't think `-1.302276:1.30227` is giving what you expected. Is this what you are looking for: `seq(-1.302276,1.30227, length.out=1000)` instead of `-1.302276,1.30227`?

Comment: Right, so combining this with @Bathsheba's answer: `X <- seq(-sqrt(3),sqrt(3),length=1000)` gives `var(X) = 1.003005`.

Answer (score 1):

The variance of a uniform distribution between `a` and `b` is `(b - a) * (b - a) / 12`.

Therefore, for the interval `[-a, +a]` to have a variance of 1, you need to set

```
a = sqrt(3)
```